# C++ code works fine but doesn't work when calling from Java (JNI)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I used to have some privilege issues when calling `ExitWindowsEX` Windows API function.

So I wrote the following code to get the privilege:

**This works fine in C++**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */

int MyExitWindows(int flag, int reason);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  MyExitWindows(EWX_SHUTDOWN, 0);
}

int MyExitWindows(int flag, int reason) {
  HANDLE hToken;
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

  //   Get   a   token   for   this   process.     

  if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    return GetLastError();

  //   Get   the   LUID   for   the   shutdown   privilege.     

  LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

  tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1; //   one   privilege   to   set           
  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

  //   Get   the   shutdown   privilege   for   this   process.     

  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0,
          (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 0);

  //   Cannot   test   the   return   value   of   AdjustTokenPrivileges.     

  ExitWindowsEx(flag, reason);
  if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    return GetLastError();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**But this doesn't work when I call it from Java**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include "com_ehsunbehravesh_jshutdown_system_Shutdowner.h"

using namespace std;

int MyExitWindows(int flag, int reason);

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_ehsunbehravesh_jshutdown_system_Shutdowner_exitWindowsEx
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong flag, jlong reason) {
  return MyExitWindows(flag, reason);
}

int MyExitWindows(int flag, int reason) {
  HANDLE hToken;
  TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tkp;

  //   Get   a   token   for   this   process.     

  int cpid = GetCurrentProcessId();
  printf("%d", cpid);
  if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken))
    return GetLastError();

  //   Get   the   LUID   for   the   shutdown   privilege.     

  LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &tkp.Privileges[0].Luid);

  tkp.PrivilegeCount = 1; //   one   privilege   to   set           
  tkp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

  //   Get   the   shutdown   privilege   for   this   process.     

  AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tkp, 0,
          (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, 0);

  //   Cannot   test   the   return   value   of   AdjustTokenPrivileges.     

  ExitWindowsEx(flag, reason);
  if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    return GetLastError();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't work" please? Crash? Error code returned from API call (which?) No error/crash but nothing seen?

Comment: `jlong` is 64-bit and I am pretty sure `int` won't be more than 32-bit in C. (Not that it should be causing you a problem either)

Comment: 1. My function return 0 and it means no error is returned by `GetLastError()` 2. As long as I know I have no error in type casting 3. By doesn't work I mean the `ExitWindowsEx` works like it does not have the full privilege (logoff works shutdown and reboot don't work)

Comment: Try checking the error codes returned by LookupPrivilegValue and AdjustTokenPrivileges.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are not using `System.exit(int)`?

Java attempts to control the shutdown of an application, perhaps it tries to prevent you doing it other ways.

Comment: Presumably because WindowsExitEx is for a different purpose: it shuts down Windows, or reboots.